# The different between Non-parametric statistics and Parametric statistics?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, definition, parametric

I have 1D data. I want to classify the data to $N$ cluster. The two common ways can use

1. Using the mean/average value as a criterion to classify
2. Assumption that the data follows a distribution with mean and variance. Then use mean and variance  as  criterions to classify

My question is that: Can I say that first method (using mean) is Non-parametric statistics method and second method( mean and variance) is Parametric statistics? Is it right?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean exactly by "use mean and variance as criterions to classify"? In the second case, are you going to perform an estimation of the parameters?

Comment: @Augustin: Right. It use assume that the data is a distribution (i.e Gaussian  with two parameters:mean and variance). Then it will try find them to fit with the distribution

Comment: Then yes, this is a parametric method. Do you want to classify with a gaussian mixture model?

Comment: Yes. How about first method. Is it name "Non-parametric statistics" or just "Non-statistics"?